# Eliminar texto dentro de parentesis en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
var example = document.getElementById('example'),
     result = document.getElementById('result');
     

  example.addEventListener('keyup',function() {
    var output = this.value,
        finish = false;
    
    while(!finish) {
      if(output.indexOf('(') >=0 && output.indexOf(')') >= 0) {
        output = output.replace(output.substr(output.indexOf('('), output.indexOf(')')  - output.indexOf('(') + 1),'');
      }
      else {
        finish = true;
      }
    }

    result.innerText = output.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim();
  });
  </script>
```

Con lo siguiente en HTML:

```html
<p>Texto con parentesis: </p>
<p>
  <textarea cols="30" rows="6" id="example"></textarea>
</p>
<p>Texto sin parentesis: </p>
<p>
  <textarea cols="30" rows="6" id="result"></textarea>
```

Este codigo funciona perfectamente en Firefox pero en IE no funciona, me pueden ayudar para que funcione en IE.

Muchas gracias!

Saludos.

Comment: No pruebes en Internet Explorer. Microsoft ya ha declarado que no es un explorador, sino una 'solución de compatibilidad'. El explorador al que Microsoft da soporte es Microsoft Edge

Comment: Si, pero necesito correrlo en IE para usarlo en mi PC antiguo, si sabes algo me puede ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta esto

```
// example es el primer textarea
var example = document.getElementById('example');
// result es el segundo textarea
var result = document.getElementById('result');
//Cuando el valor del primer textarea cambia, se ejecuta la función
example.addEventListener('change',function() {
    // La expresión regular busca desde '(' hasta el primer')', 
    // todas las vecesque se encuentre en el texto example.value
    //  y lo reemplaza por una cadea vacía. Es decir, lo borra
    const valorSinParentesis = example.value.replace(/(\([^\)]*\))/g, '');
    // Se reasigna el valor del segundo textarea por el valor 
    // del primero, luego de eliminar todos los grupos de paréntesis.
    result.value = valorSinParentesis;
});
```

Comment: Este codigo me funciono solo en Firefox en IE aun no funciona. Me gusto tu codigo porque es mas corto al que uso. Podria pasar lo que quiero eliminar entre () al pulsar un boton y aparezca en el textbox quizas asi funcione.

Comment: no tengo internet explorer. Puedes colocar una captura del error? Claramente es un problema de compatibilidad, pero el saber en qué linea está el error ayudaría a encontrar una solución que funcione para IE

Comment: En la página de mdn dice que la compatibilidad del evento keyup es desconocida. Intenta usar input en su lugar. Actualizo respuesta

Comment: Me refiero, tengo dos Textarea Arriba coloco el texto que contiene parentesis, Abajo hay otro textarea donde aparece el texto sin los parentesis. En mi IE al escribir arriba en el textarea abajo no muestra nada en cambio en Firefox si aparece el texto abajo.

Comment: Me arroja error el IE en esta linea: example.addEventListener('keyup',function() {

Comment: Correcto, el error es el evento keyup que no acepta esta propiedad o metodo.

Comment: En ese caso usa input, tal como está el código ahora mismo.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar ahora y me aparece error en esta linea: example.addEventListener('input',function() {
Podria funcionar al pulsar un boton y se muestre en el textarea.

Comment: En ese caso usa change. Ese a veces se dispara hasta que se quita el focus de los inputs, pero puede funcionar

Comment: Una explicación de lo que hace tu código la haria mas fácil de entender

Comment: Comentarios agregados @Aprendiz

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo has intentado usar expresiones regulares???
Prueba esto a ver si te ayuda.

```js
var  text = "Texto con (sin) Parentesis";
var reg = new RegExp(/([(])([\w\s]+)([)])/,'img');
result.innerHTML = text.replace(reg,"");
```

Creo que este código te funcionara en todos los navegadores.